# Cross-compiling libjpeg framework for MacOS 10.5 on macOS 10.12

Tags: macos, frameworks, libjpeg

I've tweaked a script for building libjpeg framework [here](https://gist.github.com/serser/8c6480fca04911d8e816f4f97623ecb2). The key configuration is as follows,

```
../configure --target i386-apple-darwin9.0 --build i386-apple-darwin9.0 --prefix=$OSXPREFIXDIR/osx-build --disable-dependency-tracking --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no CFLAGS="-isysroot $XCODE_ROOT/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk"
```

I've been able to create the framework, However it is still built for macOS 10.12 when I use `otool -l` to check `libjpeg` object file. Could anyone share a thought?

Answer (score 1):

I have no solution for your compilation problem but if you just want a working libjpeg binary for OS X 10.5+ then you can download it from libjpeg-turbo (either as a static library or as a dynamic one, and both libjpeg and libturbojpeg).

Check: https://libjpeg-turbo.org/Documentation/OfficialBinaries

You'll find a .dmg file on their SourceForge.

Comment: thanks a million! @nyg, I am using there-compiled dmg, it works.

Comment: well, although their dmg works, as you noted, it is not an exact answer but a workaround method.  I wish still to compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5` to the `CFLAGS`. You may not need the `target`/`build` parameters, and it may be possible to compile against the latest SDK rather than needing the 10.5 SDK.

Comment: What field are you looking at in otool?

Comment: `version` field

Comment: Hmm try adding `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5` to the LDFLAGS also

Comment: still not working, maybe I need a 10.5 Mac to do it.